# React - how set state in object of array , property text in function onChange here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have that state:

```
   state = {
        val: '',
        input: [{
            id: uuid.v4(),
            questionLabel: 'Question',
            text: '',
            typeLabel: 'Type',
            conditionLabel: 'Condition',
            types: [
                {value: '', name: ''},
                {value: 'Text', name: 'Text'},
                {value: 'Number', name: 'Number'},
                {value: 'Yes / No', name: 'Yes / No'}
            ],
            subInput: []
        }],
}
```

And that function:

```
textChangeHandler = event => {
    const text = this.state.input.map(currency => {
        const test = currency.text = event.target.value;
        return {...currency, text: test}
    });
    this.setState({text})
}
```

And i wanna change in state in input, property: `text`
But if i type in input text, it's not working, i can't type in input, and state doesn't change. How i can fix this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're directly mutating the state. And mutating the state in react application is not allowed. What you can do here is like below:

```
textChangeHandler = (event, inputIndex) => {
    const test = [...this.state.input] // first, clone the input state
    // now, you can update the text
    test[inputIndex].text = event.target.value
    this.setState({
      input: test // test is now whole updated input array
    })
}
```

**Notice**: you need to pass the index in your handler so that it can know which one to change.

If you did like below:

```
textChangeHandler = event => {
        const test = [...this.state.input]
        test.forEach(t => t.text = event.target.value)
        // but wait, event.target.value? 
        // this will change all the input with the same value
        this.setState({
          input: test
        })
    }
```

Thus, it's better to update the value using the index.

Comment: It's too not working, i have the same problem with your solution, i can't write anything in input and its unfocusing if i click a letter in keyboard.. State is changing, but have only one letter not full words or sentences. :(